# DocuSign C# SDK: ResourceToken and ViewLink are null for recipient proof endpoints

Tags: c#, sdk, docusignapi

I'm trying to use either [createRecipientProofFileLink](https://developers.docusign.com/esign-rest-api/reference/Envelopes/EnvelopeRecipients/createRecipientProofFileLink) or [createRecipientProofFileResourceToken](https://developers.docusign.com/esign-rest-api/reference/Envelopes/EnvelopeRecipients/createRecipientProofFileResourceToken) with the DocuSign C# SDK v4.3.0 (API version 2.1). When I call either with valid inputs, I can see the response body with JSON like `{"resource_token":"someresourcetoken"}` for the resource token endpoint or `{"view_link":"aworkingviewlink"}` in my Fiddler traces, but when I inspect the response in the application on Debug, both the ResourceToken and the ViewLink are null.

What am I missing?

Update: took a look at the model returned, and I think its a deserialization issue from [this](https://github.com/docusign/docusign-csharp-client/blob/2a232440abbe91f4ba6d81331e042e6a1bfed997/sdk/src/DocuSign.eSign/Model/ProofServiceViewLink.cs#L50), as the datamember expects a key of `ViewLink` but the json has `view_link`. Didn't dig too deep on the deserializer part but running this test locally confirmed it might be a problem?

[local deserialization test](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UGlKq.png)

Comment: We are looking into this. Hope to have an answer in 1-2 days.

Answer (score 0):

Recipient Proof is a new API that is not yet generally available.
I'm going to check to see if there's a way we can get it enabled sooner for all developer sandbox accounts. I'll update this thread when I have the answer.

Comment: So we are getting back content in the response, it doesn't seem to be an availability thing--my teams account is in the sandbox as far as i know? It seems like a deserialization issue from what I can see in the [model for the proof link](https://github.com/docusign/docusign-csharp-client/blob/2a232440abbe91f4ba6d81331e042e6a1bfed997/sdk/src/DocuSign.eSign/Model/ProofServiceViewLink.cs#L50) -- datamember is looking for a key called ViewLink but the body has key view_link

Comment: it appears you want to get a link to view a document, not to have proof? is that the case? 
Maybe you can start by explaining the functionality you want. not the endpoint etc. since I'm not sure you're using the right API

Comment: We have ID verification turned on, we are in the sandbox for Full ID configuration. After signers have signed / envelope is completed, i want either the link to view the ID proof or the resource token to subsequently request the proof. Using the SDK, I am able to get a response that I can see in Fiddler has a valid view link, that then is not transformed into the response in the code, and it looks to be a deserialization issue.

What I want is the view_link that I see in the response transformed into a ProofServiceViewLink with a ViewLink that is not null.

Comment: sounds like a hack, but if you can see it in fiddler, you should get it. Can you see what is the JSON that is passed? then you can serialize it yourself. 
Another option is to modify the SDK C# code. Fork https://github.com/docusign/docusign-csharp-client and change it to fit your needs.